# Remove border around content property via CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

All webkit browsers display by default a fine border around my image which i set via content:

```
content: url('myPic.png');
```

I´ve tried to remove it with: `border: 0; border-style: none;` and `text-decoration: none;` without any results. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Can you show complete & relevent code.

Comment: Try `outline: none`.

Comment: I tried and there isnt any fine border! https://plnkr.co/edit/61CvLd69A1DxMdsYh8MU?p=preview 

Could you update the plunker with your sample?

Comment: Also when i add "after" to my content the border is still there. HTML: `<div class="hintergrund bild_begruessung">
   <img id="begruessung" class="bild"/>
  </div>`  CSS: `.hintergrund {
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}` `#begruessung {
 content: url('/pics/Begr_Hoch.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

Comment: I´ve changed my <img> tag to a <div> tag and now no border. thx

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fixing default browser styles manually, nowadays people are using something like `reset.css` or `normalize.css`

Normalize.css is more convient, here is the link:

https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

Use outline: none in css on class and pseudo class :focus too